# Can modern C++ get you performance for free?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, move-semantics, c++14

It is sometimes claimed that C++11/14 can get you a performance boost even when merely compiling C++98 code. The justification is usually along the lines of move semantics, as in some cases the rvalue constructors are automatically generated or now part of the STL. Now I'm wondering whether these cases were previously actually already handled by RVO or similar compiler optimizations.

My question then is if you could give me an actual example of a piece of C++98 code that, without modification, runs faster using a compiler supporting the new language features. I do understand that a standard conforming compiler is not required to do the copy elision and just by that reason move semantics might bring about speed, but I'd like to see a less pathological case, if you will.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I am not asking whether new compilers are faster than old compilers, but rather if there is code whereby adding -std=c++14 to my compiler flags it would run faster (avoid copies, but if you can come up with anything else besides move semantics, I'd be interested, too)

Comment: Remember that copy elision and return value optimization is performed when constructing a new object using a copy constructor. However, in a copy assignment operator, there is no copy elision (how can it be, since the compiler doesn't know what to do with an already constructed object that is not a temporary). Therefore, in that case, C++11/14 wins big, by giving you the possibility of using a move assignment operator. About your question though, I don't think C++98 code should be faster if compiled by a C++11/14 compiler, maybe it is faster because the compiler is newer.

Comment: Also code that uses the standard library is potentially faster, even if you make it fully compatible with C++98, because in C++11/14 the underlying library uses internally move semantics when possible. So code that looks identical in C++98 and C++11/14 will be (possibly) faster in the latter case, whenever you use the standard library objects such as vectors, lists etc and move semantics makes a difference.

Comment: @vsoftco, That is the kind of situation I was alluding to, but could not come up with an example: From what I remember if I have to define the copy constructor, the move constructor won't be automatically generated, which leaves us with very simple classes where RVO, I think, always works. An exception might be something in conjuction with the STL containers, where the rvalue constructors are generated by the library implementer (meaning I wouldn't have to change anything in the code for it to use moves).

Comment: classes do not need to be simple in order to not have a copy constructor. C++ thrive on value semantics, and copy constructor, assignment operator, destructor etc should be the exception.

Comment: For standard collections, the implementation was (in Dinkumware anyway) tricky to avoid copies. With move, it can be written without tricks. For RVO and NRVO, you have to follow the rules to hope the compiler optimizes. With move, you can get that behavior in general and for sure. Coding styles avoid expensive operations at the expensse of clean code. So much exiating code might not show a big speedup, but moving forward you don't have to work harder and reduce maintainability to get the same level of performance.

Comment: [Pete Isensee](http://www.tantalon.com/pete.htm) gave a presentation at GDC 2012 about copies vs. moves in C++11 and performance optimization: [Faster C++: Move Constructors and Perfect Forwarding](http://www.tantalon.com/pete/files/gdc12_faster_cpp.zip). It was linked to from a blog post about recompiling unmodified C++98 code as C++11 for an instant performance increase. (Sorry, couldn't find that blog.)

Comment: @Eric Thank you for the link, it was interesting. However, having quickly looked it through, the speed advantages in it seem to come mostly from adding `std::move` and move constructors (which would require modifications to existing code). The only thing really related to my question was the sentence "You get immediate speed advantages simply by recompiling", which is not backed up by any examples (it does mention STL on the same slide, as I did in my question, but nothing specific). I was asking for some examples. If I am reading the slides wrong, do let me know.

Comment: Only the Sun is free, the rest has to be earned.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

I am aware of 5 general categories where recompiling a C++03 compiler as C++11 can cause unbounded performance increases that are practically unrelated to quality of implementation.  These are all variations of move semantics.

## `std::vector` reallocate

```
struct bar{
  std::vector<int> data;
};
std::vector<bar> foo(1);
foo.back().data.push_back(3);
foo.reserve(10); // two allocations and a delete occur in C++03
```

every time the `foo`'s buffer is reallocated in C++03 it copied every `vector` in `bar`.

In C++11 it instead moves the `bar::data`s, which is basically free.

In this case, this relies on optimizations inside the `std` container `vector`.  In every case below, the use of `std` containers is just because they are C++ objects that have efficient `move` semantics in C++11 "automatically" when you upgrade your compiler.  Objects that don't block it that contain a `std` container also inherit the automatic improved `move` constructors.

## NRVO failure

When NRVO (named return value optimization) fails, in C++03 it falls back on copy, on C++11 it falls back on move.  Failures of NRVO are easy:

```
std::vector<int> foo(int count){
  std::vector<int> v; // oops
  if (count<=0) return std::vector<int>();
  v.reserve(count);
  for(int i=0;i<count;++i)
    v.push_back(i);
  return v;
}
```

or even:

```
std::vector<int> foo(bool which) {
  std::vector<int> a, b;
  // do work, filling a and b, using the other for calculations
  if (which)
    return a;
  else
    return b;
}
```

We have three values -- the return value, and two different values within the function.  Elision allows the values within the function to be 'merged' with the return value, but not with each other.  They both cannot be merged with the return value without merging with each other.

The basic issue is that NRVO elision is fragile, and code with changes not near the `return` site can suddenly have massive performance reductions at that spot with no diagnostic emitted.  In most NRVO failure cases C++11 ends up with a `move`, while C++03 ends up with a copy.

## Returning a function argument

Elision is also impossible here:

```
std::set<int> func(std::set<int> in){
  return in;
}
```

in C++11 this is cheap: in C++03 there is no way to avoid the copy.  Arguments to functions cannot be elided with the return value, because the lifetime and location of the parameter and return value is managed by the calling code.

However, C++11 can move from one to the other.  (In a less toy example, something might be done to the `set`).

## `push_back` or `insert`

Finally elision into containers does not happen: but C++11 overloads rvalue move insert operators, which saves copies.

```
struct whatever {
  std::string data;
  int count;
  whatever( std::string d, int c ):data(d), count(c) {}
};
std::vector<whatever> v;
v.push_back( whatever("some long string goes here", 3) );
```

in C++03 a temporary `whatever` is created, then it is copied into the vector `v`.  2 `std::string` buffers are allocated, each with identical data, and one is discarded.

In C++11 a temporary `whatever` is created.  The `whatever&&` `push_back` overload then `move`s that temporary into the vector `v`.  One `std::string` buffer is allocated, and moved into the vector.  An empty `std::string` is discarded.

## Assignment

Stolen from @Jarod42's answer below.

Elision cannot occur with assignment, but move-from can.

```
std::set<int> some_function();

std::set<int> some_value;

// code

some_value = some_function();
```

here `some_function` returns a candidate to elide from, but because it is not used to construct an object directly, it cannot be elided.  In C++03, the above results in the contents of the temporary being copied into `some_value`.  In C++11, it is moved into `some_value`, which basically is free.

---

For the full effect of the above, you need a compiler that synthesizes move constructors and assignment for you.

MSVC 2013 implements move constructors in `std` containers, but does not synthesize move constructors on your types.

So types containing `std::vector`s and similar do not get such improvements in MSVC2013, but will start getting them in MSVC2015.

clang and gcc have long since implemented implicit move constructors.  Intel's 2013 compiler will support implicit generation of move constructors if you pass `-Qoption,cpp,--gen_move_operations` (they don't do it by default in an effort to be cross-compatible with MSVC2013).

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar without STL containers or will any automatically generated move constructors and such always be eligible for copy elision?

Comment: @alarge yes.  But for a move constructor to be many times more efficient than a copy constructor, it usually has to move resources instead of copying them.  Without writing your own move constructors (and just recompiling a C++03 program), the `std` library containers are all going to be updated with `move` constructors "for free", and (if you didn't block it) constructs that use said objects (and said objects) will start getting free move construction in a number of situations.  Many of those situations are covered by elision in C++03: not all.

Comment: That's a bad optimizer implementation, then, because the differently-named objects being returned don't have overlapping lifetime, RVO is theoretically still possible.

Comment: What I meant, though, with automatically generated move constructors without STL (in my comment above) was the standard dictated `default` in user defined types. If the classes don't have copy/assignment ctors nor a dtor, rvalue ctors would be generated when switching to C++11/14. I can't think of a case where these moves (with the new ctors) could not have been replaced by RVO optimizations before (again, if we didn't use `std`). Does such a case exist?

Comment: @alarge : RVO is merely an optimization, albeit a common one; it is not mandatory by any stretch, except as a QOI issue. Something in the _language grammar_ must describe these behaviors, and thus the need for rvalue references, etc.

Comment: @ildjarn I appreciate the comment, but as I mentioned in the question, I am not looking for gains between minimally conforming compiler implementations (i.e. without RVO etc.), but rather for examples where real life code might actually be sped up thanks to the new language features: i.e. where new, previously unavailable optimizations are possible at no cost to the developer.

Comment: @alarge There are places where elision fails, like when two objects with overlapping lifetimes can be elided into a third, but not each other.  Then move is required in C++11, and copy in C++03 (ignoring as-if).  Elision is often fragile in practice.  The use of `std` containers above is mostly because they are a cheap to move exoensive to copy type you get 'for free' in C++11 when recompiling C++03.  The `vector::resize` is an exception: it uses `move` in C++11.

Comment: @Ben: surely in that case RVO per se isn't *permitted*? But `std::vector<int>` has no observable side effects of copying, especially in programs that haven't overloaded global `::operator new`, so the compiler might in theory optimize by some means other than the very specific thing that the standard calls copy elision.

Comment: @alarge : That's missing my point entirely; I was specifically calling into question the statement "*I can't think of a case where these moves (with the new ctors) could not have been replaced by RVO optimizations before*". When RVO is performed, the standard requires that the code would be legal even if it weren't performed; so for non-copyable types, RVO cannot be performed unless the language supports the concept of move-only types. You simply cannot have one without the other - RVO cannot replace move semantics, it is an **optimization**.

Comment: I only see 1 general category which is move semantics, and 5 special cases of that.

Comment: @acon I do not understand the question; regardless, please ask questions using [ask question] button instead of comments in ancient answers.  It works better!

Comment: The question starts with "It is sometimes **claimed** that C++11/14 can get you a performance boost...". This answer doesn't provide any proof of such a claim (i.e. benchmarks), instead it just comes with 5 of such claims. It does provide nice and accurate explanations of why these claims **should** be faster in theory and I understand them and agree with them. In order to fully answer the question, I'm still missing a factual proof, though.

Comment: @sebro I understand, you don't consider "causes programs to not allocate many 1000s of many kilobyte allocations, and instead moves pointers around" to be sufficient. You want timed results. Microbenchmarks are no more proof of performance improvements than proof you are fundamentally doing less is. Short of a few 100 real world applications in a wide variety of industries being profiled with real world tasks profiling isn't really proof. I took vague claims about "free performance" and made them specific facts about differences in program behaviour under C++03 and C++11.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Well, you are of course right. "Proof" wasn't the right word for me to use here. What I meant was rather "This is all theory. But in the end the performance of an actual program running is what matters." Alternatively, some generated assembler showing some huge copying going on for C++03, but not for C++11 (for the very same code), would be convincing too. Simply because optimization is such a complex topic in C++ and there are so many things the compiler must/might/should/could do or not, I find it not fully convincing to argue only in a theoretical way.

Comment: @sebrockm Very generally you are correct, but in this instance the facts speak for themselves. Doing something is more expensive than not doing something, and all the above described features are about "not doing something". I don't feel we need benchmarks to accept that.

Answer (score 47):

if you have something like:

```
std::vector<int> foo(); // function declaration.
std::vector<int> v;

// some code

v = foo();
```

You got a copy in C++03, whereas you got a move assignment in C++11.
so you have free optimisation in that case.

Comment: @Yakk: How copy elision occurs in assignment ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I also believe that copy elision is not possible in an assignment, since the left hand side is already constructed and there is no reasonable way for a compiler to know what to do with the "old" data after stealing the resources from the right hand side. But maybe I'm wrong, I'd love to find out once and forever the answer. Copy elision makes sense when you copy construct, since the object is "fresh" and there is no problem of deciding what to do with the old data. As far as I know, the only exception is this: "Assignments can only be elided based on as-if rule"

Comment: Good C++03 code already did a move in this case, via `foo().swap(v);`

Comment: @BenVoigt sure, but not all code is optimized, and not all spots where this happens is easy to reach.

Comment: The copy ellision can work in an assignment, like @BenVoigt says. Better term is RVO (return value optimization) and only works if foo() has been implemented like that.